Single LoRA gives different outputs with and without merge_unload for Sequence Classification task. Which one is the correct method?
I keep everything same for Fine tuned LoRA for Sequence classification task. When I load it like:
def load_model(lora_path, device, num_labels, merge_unload = False):
    
    model = Phi3ForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("microsoft/Phi-3-mini-4k-instruct", trust_remote_code=True, 
                                                          device_map = device, 
                                                          torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
                                                          attn_implementation = "flash_attention_2", 
                                                          num_labels = num_labels)
    if model.config.pad_token_id is None:
        model.config.pad_token_id = model.config.eos_token_id
    
    peft_model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(model,
                                           lora_path, 
                                           device_map = device)
    
    peft_model = peft_model.eval().to(device)
    if merge_unload: peft_model = peft_model.merge_and_unload()
    
    return peft_model


With and without .merge_and_unload(), it gives different outputs for the same text. How can this be happening? What is the right way to do this?
LoRA Model:
PeftModelForSequenceClassification(
  (base_model): LoraModel(
    (model): Phi3ForSequenceClassification(
      (model): Phi3Model(
        (embed_tokens): Embedding(32064, 3072, padding_idx=32000)
        (embed_dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        (layers): ModuleList(
          (0-31): 32 x Phi3DecoderLayer(
            (self_attn): Phi3FlashAttention2(
              (o_proj): lora.Linear(
                (base_layer): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=3072, bias=False)
                (lora_dropout): ModuleDict(
                  (default): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
                )
                (lora_A): ModuleDict(
                  (default): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=128, bias=False)
                )
                (lora_B): ModuleDict(
                  (default): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=3072, bias=False)
                )
                (lora_embedding_A): ParameterDict()
                (lora_embedding_B): ParameterDict()
              )
              (qkv_proj): lora.Linear(
                (base_layer): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=9216, bias=False)
                (lora_dropout): ModuleDict(
                  (default): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
                )
                (lora_A): ModuleDict(
                  (default): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=128, bias=False)
                )
                (lora_B): ModuleDict(
                  (default): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=9216, bias=False)
                )
                (lora_embedding_A): ParameterDict()
                (lora_embedding_B): ParameterDict()
              )
              (rotary_emb): Phi3RotaryEmbedding()
            )
            (mlp): Phi3MLP(
              (gate_up_proj): lora.Linear(
                (base_layer): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=16384, bias=False)
                (lora_dropout): ModuleDict(
                  (default): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
                )
                (lora_A): ModuleDict(
                  (default): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=128, bias=False)
                )
                (lora_B): ModuleDict(
                  (default): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=16384, bias=False)
                )
                (lora_embedding_A): ParameterDict()
                (lora_embedding_B): ParameterDict()
              )
              (down_proj): lora.Linear(
                (base_layer): Linear(in_features=8192, out_features=3072, bias=False)
                (lora_dropout): ModuleDict(
                  (default): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
                )
                (lora_A): ModuleDict(
                  (default): Linear(in_features=8192, out_features=128, bias=False)
                )
                (lora_B): ModuleDict(
                  (default): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=3072, bias=False)
                )
                (lora_embedding_A): ParameterDict()
                (lora_embedding_B): ParameterDict()
              )
              (activation_fn): SiLU()
            )
            (input_layernorm): Phi3RMSNorm()
            (resid_attn_dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
            (resid_mlp_dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
            (post_attention_layernorm): Phi3RMSNorm()
          )
        )
        (norm): Phi3RMSNorm()
      )
      (score): ModulesToSaveWrapper(
        (original_module): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=2, bias=False)
        (modules_to_save): ModuleDict(
          (default): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=2, bias=False)
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

MERGED and Loaded Model
Phi3ForSequenceClassification(
  (model): Phi3Model(
    (embed_tokens): Embedding(32064, 3072, padding_idx=32000)
    (embed_dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    (layers): ModuleList(
      (0-31): 32 x Phi3DecoderLayer(
        (self_attn): Phi3FlashAttention2(
          (o_proj): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=3072, bias=False)
          (qkv_proj): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=9216, bias=False)
          (rotary_emb): Phi3RotaryEmbedding()
        )
        (mlp): Phi3MLP(
          (gate_up_proj): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=16384, bias=False)
          (down_proj): Linear(in_features=8192, out_features=3072, bias=False)
          (activation_fn): SiLU()
        )
        (input_layernorm): Phi3RMSNorm()
        (resid_attn_dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        (resid_mlp_dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        (post_attention_layernorm): Phi3RMSNorm()
      )
    )
    (norm): Phi3RMSNorm()
  )
  (score): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=2, bias=False)
)

